# Parsing UDP header within IP header VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sockets, networking, udp, ip

I am making a network sniffer. I have opened a raw socket listening on my main network interface (192.168.2.11). The code is not really required, but if you need it I can provide. I then create a `MemoryStream` from a received packet (which should contain an IP header, followed by a UDP header, which is finally followed by a datagram). I convert this `MemoryStream` to a `BinaryReader`, and use the following process to parse the IP header

```
Version and header length        BinaryReader.ReadByte() 'As two nibbles make a byte
Type of service                  BinaryReader.ReadByte()
Total length                     BinaryReader.ReadInt16()
Identification                   BinaryReader.ReadInt16()
Flags and offset                 BinaryReader.ReadInt16() 'As 3 bits + 13 bits is 16
Time to live                     BinaryReader.ReadByte()
Protocol                         BinaryReader.ReadByte()
Checksum                         BinaryReader.ReadInt16()
Source address                   BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
Destination address              BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
```

(More processing is done to this data, but no changes are made to the `BinaryReader`)

I then query the `Version` field to see whether it is 17 (UDP), if it is I proceed to the next step, otherwise I discard the process.

Now I check whether the Internet Header Length (IHL) is 5 (which is 5 * 32 or 160 bits, or 20 bytes). I do this to make sure my program does not trip on unnecessary IP options. If it is not 5, I discard the process.

The IP header parses perfectly... Now using the exactly same `BinaryReader`, I attempt to parse the encapsulated UDP header. The code I am using for this is

```
Out("Source port?: " & IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(bin.ReadInt16()))
Out("Destination port?: " & IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(bin.ReadInt16()))
Out("Length?: " & IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(bin.ReadInt16()))
Out("Checksum?: " & IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(bin.ReadInt16()))
```

But I always get something absurd... Here is the output of my console application

```
Source port?: -364
Destination port?: 53
Length?: 35
Checksum?: -7570
```

Destination looks good, 53 for DNS, then length looks good too, but the source? How can a port be negative? And the checksum might be allowed to be negative, I am not sure. What is wrong with my code? If you need the IP header output, it is here...

```
Version: 4 (0100)
Internet header length: 5
    Words (32 bits): 5
    Octets (8 bits): 20
    Bits (1 bit): 160
Type of service: 0x00000000
    Precedence: 000 (Routine)
    Delay: 0 (Normal Delay)
    Throughput: 0 (Normal Throughput)
    Reliability: 0 (Normal Reliability)
Total length: 55
Identification: 2866
Flags: 0x00
    Reserved: False
    Don't Fragment: False
    More Fragments: False
Fragment offset: 0
Time to live: 128
Protocol: 17 (UDP)
Header checksum: -21977
Source address: 184723648 (192.168.2.11)
Destination address: 16951488 (192.168.2.1)
Payload length (bits): 288
```

Comment: [UDP port numbers go from 0 to 65535](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) so you'll want a UInt16 there, not an Int16.

Comment: "_I then query the `Version` field to see whether it is 17 (UDP), if it is I proceed to the next step, otherwise I discard the process._" That makes no sense. The `Version` field is the IP version, and it should be either `4` or `6`. It is the `Protocol` field that should be `17`.

Comment: @RonMaupin My bad, in the code I actually do query the Protocol, but I accidentally typed Version.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Great, I'll change it to UInt16, thank you :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hmm, seems that ReadUInt16 gives me 361496576 when I should get 5516... I am using IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder, do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem wasn't my parsing method (I knew it), it was the data returned by the raw socket. When I use a hex dump provided by Wireshark, it goes great.